# Android: View background doesn't go bigger than parent

Tags: android, view, background, shapes

this is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/intro_base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clipChildren="false">
<View
        android:id="@+id/bg"
        android:layout_width="2000dp"
        android:layout_height="2000dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/intro_bg"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is intro_bg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/dark_teal_blue"/>
</shape>
```

in may activity I change the bg `View` heights and width and set them to something bigger than size of the screen to have a circle which cover all the screen but when I run the app on device I got this:
[image: view background convret to oval]

I want a circle bigger than screen , then animate it to scale down, but my view's background doesn't go bigger than parent. Why? How can I have circle bigger than device screen which covers all of the screen?

Comment: Generally speaking, the size of view is limited by its parent. If you want your  view to be bigger than parent, you shall overwrite the method onMeasure.

Comment: something strange!! Are you sure? so What does `clipChildren` do?